# What is the weight of an astral construct?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

Nowhere in the astral construct power description does it say what the weights of the resulting constructs are.

I have a feeling that I've seen somewhere that ectoplasm has negligible weight, but I couldn't find that information when I searched the psionics books.

Does anyone know what the weights for astral constructs are?

Comment: Our group just used similar sized "things" .. ie Bear, Dinosaurs, etc ... to get an rough rounding of weight when it was needed :) In other words, we assumed they'd weigh about the same as something of equal mass. Not sure how "correct" this was, but it was the simplest ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### This isn't defined.

I'd like to be wrong, but I have not seen any D&D book mention how much an Astral Construct (or ectoplasm in general) weighs.

Lacking specific rules, an Astral Construct should be assumed to have a weight within the [range defined for its size](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/movementPositionAndDistance.htm#bigandLittleCreaturesInCombat).

Comment: According to *Ghostwalk* 10 lbs. of ectoplasm covers a Medium creature (and 5 lbs. a Small creature). Someone mathier than I can probably work out something from there.

Comment: Hmm. Unless the thickness is defined, I rather doubt it's going to give anything concrete...

Comment: You're right, but the slippery stuff is giving a bonus to Escape Artist skill checks and doesn't inhibit spellcasting (including manipulating material components), so my guess would be *not very.* Moisturizing cream thick, maybe? (I guess we'd also need to know if, like cheap chocolate bunnies, astral constructs are hollow.)

Comment: They are solid because they hit hard. Ectoskeleton from http://dsp-d20-srd.wikidot.com/ectoskeleton allows you to enter them and move freely in them, so my guess is they work somewhat like riverine. A liquid with a solid outer part.